# sql divide time using between in case when

Tags: sql, group-by, case

I have a data set
exit table

```
exit_id | clicktime
123     | 15:46:41
424     | 12:43:22
343     | 2:44:33
543     | 20:44:33
```

divide the clicktime into parts

[12am - 6am]

[6am - 9am]

[9am - 12pm]

[12pm - 3pm]

[3pm - 6pm]

[6pm - 9pm]

[9pm - 12am]

Desired Output

```
exit_id | Most_Active_Time
123     | 3pm - 6pm
424     | 12pm - 3pm
343     | 12am - 6am
543     | 6pm - 9pm
```

Comment: What have you tried?  There is nothing complicated about the `case` expression.  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I couldn't solve can u help me with the query

Comment: I am trying case only

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
with
w_query as (
    select 123 as exit_id, '15:16:41'::time as click_time
    union
    select 424, '12:43:22'::time
    union
    select 343, '2:44:33'::time
    union
    select 543, '20:44:33'::time
)
select
    exit_id,
    case
        when click_time between '15:00:00'::time and '18:59:59'::time then '3pm - 6pm'
        when click_time between '12:00:00'::time and '15:59:59'::time then '12pm - 3pm'
        else 'null'
    end
from w_query
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.